# Is there a way to report spam, or OT comments on Stack Exchange blogs?

Tags: support, spam, blog, blog-overflow

Is there a way to flag spam comments, or other OT comments on a Stack Exchange blog? Is there a way for blogs associated to Stack Exchange 2.0 sites?

I just noticed the last two comments on https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/respect-the-community-your-own-and-others/: One seems a tentative of spamming (without any links), and the other is an OT comment about vacation.

Comment: Hey, it's custom jerseys again. By the way, there *is* a link: Clicking the username takes you to his "homepage".

Comment: Yes, but it takes you to the website they entered, not a site where you can flag their posts as spam.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Currently, no. There's also no way for:

- Users to edit comments once submitted (similar to how comments work on the main site)
- Users to up vote comments (similar to how comments work on the main site)
- Comments to be threaded (not going to happen, we don't do this on the main site either)
- Markdown to be used

I think what we need is some of our WP Wizards from Wordpress SE to come together and give Stack Exchange a better comment system delivered by a plugin. Why? I doubt it would be implemented any other way. If you even *mention* PHP at StackHQ people rush to you with tissue.

If something totally awesome was gift wrapped on Github, I'm *sure* some swag would go out to  those involved. If Stack Exchange disagrees on the swag, I'll personally write thank you notes in crayon and send them out to those involved.

Comment: What about Discus or some existing commenting system? Why build something new. ;)

Comment: `If you even mention PHP at StackHQ people rush to you with tissue.` - Gesundheit.

Comment: @jmort253 Not quite sure if SE would be fond of a third party tool for that. Kind of a throwback to the uservoice days, imho.

Comment: Maybe, but Wordpress is sort of a third party tool too. ;)

Comment: @jmort253 By third party, I meant hosted elsewhere. Historically SE does not pull content into the DOM that they themselves don't generate or have full control over. WP is self hosted. I agree with not reinventing the blog, but comment systems for WP do kind of suck, a better one would not be a waste.

Comment: @TimPost We do use Disqus on the Server Fault blog. Not sure why or why it's not also used on the main blog, though.

Comment: @AnnaLear Ah I did not know that, the last time I read it .. it was just Vanilla WP for comments.

Comment: I hear that both rchern *and* Jarrod were knee-deep in the PHP last week, getting SE authentication working for the Super User blog. Oddly enough, I haven't seen either one around much this week...

Comment: @Shog9 Well that makes sense, most rehab clinics don't let you communicate with the outside world for the first couple of weeks.

Answer (score 5):

You just did!

Thanks, those comments have been deleted.

I do check on them from time-to-time, but these apparently slipped through the cracks.

Comment: Also one on the new editing blog.