# Why there isn't a way to raise a spam flag on SE blogs?

Tags: feature-request, spam, blog

I was peacefully reading the Gaming.SE blog, when suddenly, *GASP* I [found spam!!!](http://blog.gaming.stackexchange.com/2013/03/crysis-3-of-benchmarks-and-borrowing/#comment-58957). I diligently look for a way to get rid of it... but found none. [Apparently this functionality is not implemented in the SE blogs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/151908/213575), so I'm doing a feature request. Ah, also, if someone is kind enough to remove that spam, thanks! D:

Comment: Maybe I'm blind, but what spam?

Comment: @Daedalus [They removed it](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/35?m=14113844#14113844)

Comment: Alright then, thanks for the clarification, heh.